# WP rocket cache issue

Tags: wordpress, caching, browser-cache

I am working on a website and there is `wp-rocket` in a website.I have enabled the feature of cache.

Now problem is when wp rocket creates cache, it cannot show my css and js changes in website. So I have to hard dump the cache from website which is painstaking. `Wp rocket` supports cache busting technique but is not working.I have tested the query string to bust cache but it didn't work too. How can I resolve the issue without any custom solution and  using `wp rocket plugin`?

Comment: Create a staging/local version of the site, disable the plugin there, do your work, then update the production site with your changes?

Comment: We don't want to disable the plugin.What we want is whenever we update anything the changes show automatically without hard dump cache.

Comment: Then you'll need to reach out to the WP Rocket team and ask them to help you figure out why the "cache busting technique" doesn't work for you. There's no other way around it if you don't want to disable the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

use versioning when updating the css files

> style.css?ver=1

so when doing any change just update the file version.
[Check this link](https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/966-css-changes-dont-show-up)

Answer (score 0):

The following filter will disable page cache while keeping optimizations:

```
add_filter( 'do_rocket_generate_caching_files', '__return_false' );
```